# set tab color, divider and text alignment in android

Tags: android, fragment, android-tabhost, android-fragmentactivity

How to set text alignment and divider color in an tabhost widget.

```
mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);


    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("key", "Category");
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Category").setIndicator("Category"),
            CategoryFragment.class, b);

    b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("key", "Activity");
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Activity")
            .setIndicator("Activity"), ActivityFragment.class, b);

    b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("key", "Chart");
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("Chart").setIndicator("Chart"),
            ChartFragment.class, b);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_selector);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_selector);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_selector);

    mTabHost.getTabWidget().setShowDividers(TabWidget.SHOW_DIVIDER_MIDDLE);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.color.white);
```

tab_selector xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/brown" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/black" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/red"/>

</selector>
```

layout xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/realtabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foreground="@color/final_red"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

        android:foregroundGravity="center" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have used setDividerDrawable but I can't see divider after executing code.
Also I want to show divider between tabs. How can I do.
In the attached picture I want divider between category, activity and chart.
And text should be centre aligned

[image]

Comment: add 1 line before setdividerdrawble tabhost.getTabWidget().setShowDividers(TabWidget.SHOW_DIVIDER_MIDDLE);

Comment: having you checkded?>

Comment: @DigveshPatel Check my updated post and logcat error

Comment: add this line in TabWidget "android:divider="@android:color:white"

Comment: @yuva check this http://pastie.org/9793998 you have just swap the line

Comment: @JigarShekh check my layout xml

Comment: @DigveshPatel Not working

Comment: Where is TabWidget in Layout.xml, are you making it programmatically.

Comment: @DhavalGondaliya Yes

Answer (score 0):

This is  How i made `TabView` using  `FragmentTabHost` and `TabWidget`. Try this:

```
<android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ff0000"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                android:showDividers="middle"
                android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
                android:splitMotionEvents="true"
                android:tabStripEnabled="true"
                android:textAlignment="inherit"
                android:textDirection="inherit" />
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost>
```

**EDIT**

```
private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
SharedPreferences preferences;
Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    preferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("My Loging",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    editor = preferences.edit();

    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(),
            android.R.id.tabcontent);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("Home").setIndicator("Home",
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home_icon)),
            HomeFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("Product").setIndicator("Product",
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.home_icon)),
            ProductFragment.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("MyOrder").setIndicator("MyOrder",
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_order_icon)),
            MyOrderFragment.class, null);

    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("AboutUs").setIndicator("About Us",
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.history_icon)),
            AboutUsFragment.class, null);

    mTabHost.addTab(
            mTabHost.newTabSpec("ContactUs").setIndicator("Contact Us",
                    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.history_icon)),
            ContactUsFragment.class, null);

}
```

Comment: For tabs its taking default color, How can I add custom background as shown in picture? Also TextAlignment center not working

Comment: Your code giving same thing which i were getting  before adding background to tabs in my code

Comment: make your your divider color and background color is different.

Comment: Yes I'm using total different color.But in your case how can i set my own color for tabs.I'm not able to do this

Comment: Your code also showing my fragment view on tab selection. Have you checked it at your place by executing code

Comment: This is my working project code.IT was as requirement of tabview.

Comment: I am using background color in XML file. But it may be system default color below API lvl 10.

Comment: Yes.Default its showing divider.but when you want to add color its not showing